# I'm checking Ms Office version

Tags: ms-office, version

I'm currently maintaining an old plugin for Office. Current solution has a method for determining what version of Office is currently installed. It looks into the registration db for `PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c` and the `Version=`. All good and dandy. For Office 2003 the `Version=11`, for Office 2007 the `Version=12`. For Office 2010 the `Version=14`. Ehm what? Are we not counting 10-11-12-13-14-15 etc anymore?

Perhaps my google-fu is failing me telling me the word/number I seek is 14, or I'm missing some detail. Looking at MSDN and using `<`insert curse word`>` search engine was also unsuccesful.

Is Office 2010 `Version=14` ?

Unfortunately for me, I only have Office 2007, so no help there. I'm not asking about How to get version, that is done already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 13 is skipped for reasons of superstition (triskaidekaphobia, the aversion to the number 13). So indeed, Office 2007 is internally versioned Office 12, and Office 2010 is Office 14.

Also check out [this video on Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/ButWhy/There-is-no-Office-13-But-Why).

Comment: Thx, I had a suspicion on this, and my google-fu failed me then. Ok how do I reward the right answer now. Two ppl - same time - same answer. I'm afraid Bolt is listed first so it must have been him who was first. Sorry Quimby.

Comment: @DoStuffZ: actually, Quimby's answer was first — by a mere 15 seconds. Our answers are randomly-ordered, unless Matt's vote was already cast before you saw our answers, in which case mine would indeed be listed first.

Comment: The [`FAQ`](http://winsupersite.com/article/faqtip/microsoft-office-14-faq) link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia: The version number 13 was skipped because of the aversion to the number 13.

Answer (score 0):

```
MS 2007: <AppVersion>12.0300</AppVersion> 
MS 2010: <AppVersion>14.0300</AppVersion> 
MS 2013: <AppVersion>15.0300</AppVersion> 
MS 2016: <AppVersion>16.0300</AppVersion>
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.